# Excel button disabled when using COM object declared with WithEvents

Tags: excel, vba, events, com

I have an Excel sheet, with a button on it (the ActiveX version).
In the button click code I'm using a COM object. I need to catch events so the object is declared with **WithEvents**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_object As MyObjectWithEvents

Private Sub Button_Click()
  Set m_object = New MyObjectWithEvents
  m_object.DoStuff
End Sub
```

Just after adding the code, it works. But after closing and reopening the workbook, the button stops working.
The button is still clickable but nothing happens. Button_Click() does never get called anymore. Another strange thing is hovering over the button shows a cross (like when you are on a cell) rather than the usual mouse arrow.

As soon as I remove the **WithEvents** keyword, the button is working again, That is, Button_Click gets executed.

Moving all this out of the sheet code and into a class works. But still, I'm curious of what happens. Sounds like something related to security, but I could not find anything online.

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: That's fairly unclear.  Do the button stop firing its Click event or does the MyObjectWithEvents no longer fires its events?  Do you ever set m_object back to Nothing?

Comment: the button stop firing its Click even. I've edited, hope its more clear.